# Scale Gradient Step Taken by Tensorflow Optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have collections of `Worker` networks and a `Master` network. The Master network outputs probabilities that each `Worker` network will output the correct response. Essentially, all the `Worker` networks take a vote as to what the correct output is, and the `Master` network weights each vote. When training each `Worker` network, I would like to scale the gradient step taken by the optimizer `tf.train.AdamOptimizer` by the weighting outputted by the Master network. I am using `tf.layers` to build my networks. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But what is your _question_?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I'd like to know how to scale the gradient step taken by the optimizer during training. Currently, I just feed a loss function and a learning rate into the optimizer, and it simply does its thing. But I'd like to further scale the gradient step it takes by the values outputted by the master network.